# Alternating between 2 different templates in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have 2 different templates for my model's views. Each time the models are fetched from the database, the first 3 models (#1, 2, 3) fetched from the backend will have the view created using the first template, the next 4 models (#4, 5, 6, 7) will use the second template, the next 3 models (#8, 9, 10) will use the first template and so on.

**Problem:** How will I introduce this alternating template using backbone.js?

**JS Code**

```
// Views

PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html('');
        _.each(this.model.models, function(photo) {
            $(this.el).append(new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagNAme: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_PhotoListView').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, your `PhotoListView` is wrapping a collection so you should be using `this.collection` inside the view and `new PhotoListView({ collection: c })` to create it. Views treat the [`collection` option similarly to how they treat `model`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and attributes.

Using the right names will help prevent confusion. Also, views have [some Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) already mixed in so you can say `this.collection.each(...)` instead of `_.each(this.collection.models, ...)` or `_(this.collection.models).each(...)`. You can also use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead of `$(this.el)`.

And now on to your real problem. You can add two templates to your per-model view:

```
PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template0: _.template($('#the-first-template-id').html()),
    template1: _.template($('#the-other-template-id').html()),
    //...
});
```

and an option to tell it which one to use:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.template = this['template' + options.template_number];
    //...
}
```

Then you just need to specify the `group` option from the collection view. Underscore's [`each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) passes the iteration index to the callback function as the second argument so you just need a bit of integer math to figure out which `template_number` to use:

```
this.collection.each(function(photo, i) {
    // Grouped in threes and you're alternating between two templates.
    var n = Math.floor(i / 3) % 2; 
    var v = new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo, template_number: n });
    this.$el.append(v.render().el);
}, this);
```

Comment: Question : render would be called for each element and view would be refreshed. Can we optimize this?

Comment: @AjayBansal: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: When would the render be called ? - for each iteration in "each" loop .right?

Comment: @AjayBansal: Yes, how else would you use the `PhotoListItemView`s? Perhaps you should ask a question so that you can provide more context, comments are a bit limited.